# Call asp.net mvc action from html email / widget like functionality?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I am designing a system that needs to be able to call/inject a widget into an html email as soon as the recipient opens it. Just like when a html email calls the images from a remote server on open.

I just need to insert a few lines of text from a remote server, running asp.net mvc.

As most html emails are read in a email client, putting a reference to a remote js file seems like a bad solution as most good email clients will raise red flags when detecting js, obviously.

An alternative would be to insert an img tag into the html and have it load an image returned by an mvc action using its "src" attribute, and dynamically create the image on the server.

You guys have any any ideas? Much appreciated... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The image is the only solution that doesn't require JavaScript or an IFrame, which would probably be rejected by the email client.

That being said, by default many email clients also do not download images.

Is it absolutely necessary to display the widget without having the user click a link?

If so, my choice would be the dynamic image and I would add a line to the message urging the recipient to allow image loading.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Displaying the widget without clicking would be preferable, yes... But I'm begining to think it's not possible...?

Answer (score 1):

You can't update anything post-send in the email by fetching it from the server, except for as you mentioned, a dynamic image based on a fixed url within the html code. You can set url params or unique urls before the send, but once the email is gone, the html is static.

You can run any javascript from a href location with no issues, providing you link to a .html page and not a .js directly (never tried this but I'd imagine you're right that it would flag spam filters).